# Phase-shift of summed $\cos$ series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

I can phase-shift the curve

$$\sum_{k=0}^R \cos\frac{k\pi x}{R}$$

by $+n$ by replacing $x$ with $(x-n)$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^R \cos\frac{k\pi (x-n)}{R}=\sum_{k=0}^R \cos(\frac{k\pi x}{R}-\frac{kn\pi}{R})$$

Somehow, individual instances of $\sum_{k=0}^R \cos(\frac{k\pi x}{R}-\frac{kn\pi}{R})$ sum to produce the desired phase-shift $n$. But I am puzzled about how this works.

Is there a formulaic way to explain it? Is there a way to split out some function of the $-\frac{kn\pi}{R}$ element so that it is separately summed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This - "Somehow, individual instances of  ... (sic.) ... sum to produce the desired phase-shift $n$ " - this is not true. All elements are shifted by the amount $n$ so overall curve also shifts by that amount.

Comment: OK. I assumed that the shifts summed too. Rookie mistake. Thank you.

Comment: No "answered" button...?

Comment: Not sure what you mean :) There is no answer posted!

Comment: Maybe $cos(a-b)=cos(a)cos(b)+sin(a)sin(b)$ helps?

Comment: I tried that, but got nowhere.(And I was wrong about the rookie mistake!

Comment: I tried that, but got nowhere. And I was wrong about the rookie mistake! the issue is that, for $R=3$, say: $cos(\frac{0n\pi x}{3}−\frac{0n\pi}{3})\ne cos(\frac{1n\pi x}{3}−\frac{1n\pi}{3})\ne cos(\frac{2n\pi x}{3}−\frac{2n\pi}{3})$ and so on.

Comment: Apologies. I meant the phase-shifts are not equal.

Comment: Periods of these different cos terms are also not equal. $f(x) -> f(x-k) $shifts the function by $k$ units. End of story. Consider $f(x) = g(x)+g(2x)$, where $g(x)$ is periodic. Then $f(x-k)$ shifts $f(x)$ by k units. So $f(x-k) = g(x-k) + g(2(x-k)) = g(x-k) + g(2x - 2k)$. Yes phase shifts are different, but in total they account for periodicity so as to produce same shift in all terms. Period of $g(2x)$ is half of $g(x)$ so we need it to have twice the change in phase as that of $g(x)$ to get same shift.

Comment: Just so I'm 100% clear on this, could you confirm that what you mean is that $\sum_{k=0}^R \frac{(kn\pi)}{R}=n$ for all (natural number) values of $R$?